# rails 4- Gem prawn pdf landscape rendering using new controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, prawn

I want to generate a PDF file in landscape format using gem Prawn in Rails 4. I read the following option in manual which works fine.

```
pdf = Prawn::Document.new(:page_size => "A4", :page_layout => :landscape)
```

However, I want to write all rendering code in a separate controller "StudentVoucherPdf" in apps/pdfs/student_voucher_pdf.rb and I am calling this controller as:

```
pdf = StudentVoucherPdf.new(@student)
```

Now I am unable to figure out where I should give :page_layout => :landscape command. Kindly help. If you need to know any other thing, please ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to descend your `StudentVoucherPdf` from `Prawn::Document`, so you will be able to use the methods of pdf codument from itself:

```
class StudentVoucherPdf < Prawn::Document
   def initializer student
      @student = student
      super :page_size => "A4", :page_layout => :landscape
   end
end
```